# error package android.support.design.widget does not exist

Tags: java, android

when i try to build my android project i get this errors

> Error:(8, 37) error: package android.support.design.widget does not
>   exist Error:(18, 9) error: cannot find symbol class TabLayout
>   Error:(18, 32) error: cannot find symbol class TabLayout Error:(21,
>   33) error: cannot find symbol variable TabLayout Error:(27, 56) error:
>   package TabLayout does not exist Error:(48, 36) error: cannot find
>   symbol variable menu Error:(28, 57) error: package TabLayout does not
>   exist Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details. Error:(55, 23) error: cannot find symbol variable action_settings

and this is my code

```
package com.chaos.creativo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;

/**
 * Created by ahmed on 3/7/2016.
 */
public class Signin_up extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signing_up);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("SIGN IN"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("SIGN UP"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PageAdapter adapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

my build.gradle

```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
> 
> android {
>     compileSdkVersion 23
>     buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
> 
>     defaultConfig {
>         applicationId "com.chaos.creativo"
>         minSdkVersion 18
>         targetSdkVersion 23
>         versionCode 1
>         versionName "1.0"
>     }
>     buildTypes {
>         release {
>             minifyEnabled false
>             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>         }
>     } }
> 
> dependencies {
>     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
>     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
>     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
>     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
>     compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
>     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
>     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2'
>     compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2' }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are using android studio then put following in gradle file and rebuild.

```
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
```

If version 23.2.1 won't support, use 23.1.1

Comment: you should update your answer to use the 23.2 support library

Answer (score 5):

Replace

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

with

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

in your build.gradle

Answer (score 3):

I solved same error by adding this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In case if you are mixing **Support** library with **AndroidX** library which is not permissible. Remove **support** library and use **AndroidX**. To migrate AndroidX correctly follow below steps:
**1**.**Select Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX
**2**.Press Do Refatcor**

Answer (score 1):

For API 25 this worked for me:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

On API 26 this works:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
```