# Android Studio androidx.coordinatorlayout error and how to set up 3Dot Menu?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have the following problem. My android studio is showing the error, which is alredy written in the title [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uT8T4.png). I was trying to implement the nice 3 dot menu in the top right corner. Would be very nice if someone could tell me what the issue is...

The error im getting when trying to gradle is:

`C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\BluetoothCar\app\src\main\java\com\car\bluetooth\bluetoothcar\MainActivity.java:11: error: package android.support.design.widget does not exist
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;`

`C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\BluetoothCar\app\src\main\java\com\car\bluetooth\bluetoothcar\MainActivity.java:12: error: package android.support.v7.widget does not exist
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;`

I already tried to import the v7.widget.toolbar, but it marks the v7 red and says cant resolve symbol.

MainActivity.java :

```
package com.car.bluetooth.bluetoothcar;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//SeekBars

private SeekBar seekBarGas;
private TextView textViewGas;

private SeekBar seekBarSteering;
private TextView textViewSteering;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    seekBarGas = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarGas);
    textViewGas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewGas);
    seekBarGas.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            textViewGas.setText(progress + "  /  " + seekBarGas.getMax());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            seekBarGas.setProgress(0);
        }
    });

    seekBarSteering = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarSteering);
    textViewSteering = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSteering);
    seekBarSteering.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            textViewSteering.setText(progress + "  /  " + seekBarSteering.getMax());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            seekBarSteering.setProgress(3);
        }
    });








}

}
```

content_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBarGas"
    android:layout_width="237dp"
    android:layout_height="117dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:max="5"
    android:progress="0"
    android:rotation="-90"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gas_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Gas"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/seekBarGas"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewGas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gas_text"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    tools:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBarSteering"
    android:layout_width="199dp"
    android:layout_height="106dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:max="6"
    android:progress="3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/steeringText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="Lenkung"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.86"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewSteering"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="88dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.842"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.car.bluetooth.bluetoothcar">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Build.grade (App)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.car.bluetooth.bluetoothcar"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-alpha05'
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-alpha05'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-1.0.0- 
rc01.aar\f57a72ca523e97bfd49e26fe0ca995bd\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml:9:5- 
   12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
```

C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\BluetoothCar\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

```
 C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\material-1.0.0-rc01.aar\5165e838ec45d5f110381d4afe9056c6\res\values\values.xml:161:5-202: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

  C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\material-1.0.0-rc01.aar\5165e838ec45d5f110381d4afe9056c6\res\values\values.xml:161:5-202: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

  error: failed linking references.
```

Comment: Can you paste your dependencies from Gradle please.

Comment: I think your problem is you are not able to see the preview. Isn't it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error package android.support.design.widget does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843655/error-package-android-support-design-widget-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will solve your first issue with coordinateLayout

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

Add this dependency to your app.gradle file

And this will also solve your issue with AppBarLayout

As the errors are clearly saying that you do not have the design package,

```
C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\BluetoothCar\app\src\main\java\com\car\bluetooth\bluetoothcar\MainActivity.java:11: error: **package android.support.design.widget does not exist**
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;

C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\BluetoothCar\app\src\main\java\com\car\bluetooth\bluetoothcar\MainActivity.java:12: error: **package android.support.v7.widget does not exist**
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

Edit:

Edit this portion

[image]

with

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-alpha05'
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-alpha05'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

There is a duplicate of appcompat and the other dependecies are not looking good with versions.

Comment: Thank you ,my coordinateLayout issue is solved, but I cant import v7.widget, because its marked red as seen here: https://imgur.com/a/tJ0kR4e It also says cannot resolve symbol.

Comment: Welcome :) ! I have edited my answer.Please check it.

Comment: Sadly still wont work :/ Is it normal, that the toolbar is so small? https://imgur.com/a/GxhTdaA And I will put my dependencies in the post as well, If this helps

Comment: Yes please post if I can help you anyhow.

Comment: I also have updated my answer as per your updated question.Please check it.

Comment: My compile sdk version is now set to 27 and I replaced my dependencies with yours. Now it says Cannot resolve symbol for "AppBarLayout" and "Toolbar" as you can see here https://imgur.com/a/tlQHU0K . If you wonder why I changed the compile sdk verion... the dependencies said it would not work if its set to 28 as it was. So I changed that one.

Comment: Can you please send your full app.gradle file?

Comment: Please give 27  to both the targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion.Then tell me.I think this time it will run properly.Because targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion should have the same version.

Comment: Still wont work I pasted the error code in the question.

Comment: Hey this is working now.Now you don't have issues with depedencies and version.Now it is giving error in other section of your project. i.e, error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

Comment: You have to focus on resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius.Where have used this attr/dialogCornerRadius,android:attr/ttcIndex & android:attr/fontVariationSettings in your project?

Comment: I have littelary no idea,but I have to say my toolbar is still not showing. Looks like this https://imgur.com/a/GxhTdaA

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 12):

For androidx use following dependency

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0"
}
```

Ref - https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/coordinatorlayout