# Assistance with android studio gradle

Tags: android, gradle

This is my first post but I need some help,
This is my error :

```
error: package android.support.design.widget does not exist
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
```

This is my gradle codes

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.weatherviewerappeliasshahsamand"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843655/error-package-android-support-design-widget-does-not-exist ?

Comment: I thought material library is not downloaded. You make some change to build.gradle,then press "Sync", might resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have both support library and androidx library in your project...I think this must be issue. 
You can use:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
```

Instead of:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

And you can replace your other support library codes and use androidx Library

Answer (score 0):

You have migrated some of the dependencies to AndroidX but still some of the dependencies doesn't seems to match with android X .You will have to replace some of your dependencies to the latest version:
Replace

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
```

with

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
```

Now as the error message please replace the widgets to androidx or Migrate by

```
Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX > Migrate
```